# Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So first of all, I'm working with a JSON but I can't seem to put it here in my snippet so I'll just explain what I'm trying to do:

When you load the page it shows a collection of 5 phones and it has a validation form with a select and a submit. In the select there are options with the unique brands of the phones. If I select 'iPhone' for example i only want the phones with the brand 'iPhone' to show.

Everything works untill now but if i try to filter the list i get an error 'Cannot read property filter of undefined', i suppose because i return null but i can't seem to figure out the solution. I did some research and saw this question was already asked multiple times but i still can't find how to do it myself in this code of mine.

Any help would be useful thanks!

I am working with es6 btw:

```js
{
  let phones;

  const initValidation = () => {
    const $form = document.querySelector(`form`);
    $form.noValidate = true;
    $form.addEventListener(`submit`, handleSubmitForm);
  }

  const handleSubmitForm = e => {
    const $form = e.target;
    e.preventDefault();
    if($form.checkValidity()){
      const filteredPhones = getFilteredPhones();
      createPhone(filteredPhones);
    }
  };

  const getFilteredPhones = () => {
    const brand = document.querySelector(`.brands`).value;
    return phones.filter(phone => phone.brand == brand);
  };

  const setBrandOptions = brands => {
    const $select = document.querySelector(`.brands`);
    brands.sort().forEach(brand => {
      const $option = document.createElement(`option`);
      $option.value = brand;
      $option.textContent = brand;
      $select.appendChild($option);
    });
  };

  const getUniqueBrands = phones => {
    const uniqueBrands = [];
    // for (let i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
    //   if (!uniqueBrands.includes(phones[i].brand)){
    //     uniqueBrands.push(phones[i].brand);
    //     console.log(phones[i].brand);
    //   }
    // }
    phones.forEach(phone => {
      if(!uniqueBrands.includes(phone.brand)){
        uniqueBrands.push(phone.brand);
        console.log(phone.brand);
      }
    });
    return uniqueBrands;
  };


  const createPhone = phones => {
    const $div = document.createElement(`div`);
    document.querySelector(`section`).appendChild($div);

    const $img = document.createElement(`img`);
    $img.setAttribute('src', phones.image);
    $div.appendChild($img);

    const $title = document.createElement(`h2`);
    $title.textContent = phones.name;
    $div.appendChild($title);

    const $ul = document.createElement(`ul`);
    $div.appendChild($ul);
    $librand = document.createElement(`li`);
    $librand.textContent = phones.brand;
    $ul.appendChild($librand);
    $liyear = document.createElement(`li`);
    $liyear.textContent = phones.year;
    $ul.appendChild($liyear);
  };

  const parseJSON = phones => {
    console.log(phones);
    phones.forEach(phone => createPhone(phone));
    const brands = getUniqueBrands(phones);
    setBrandOptions(brands);
  };

  const initJSON = () => {
    const url = "assets/data/phones.json";
    fetch(url)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(jsonObject => parseJSON(jsonObject));
  };

  const init = () => {
    initJSON();
    initValidation();
  };

  init();
}
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
section{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 3rem;
  padding-right: 3rem;
}
h1{
  border-bottom: .1rem solid black;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
img{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
h2{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
ul{
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
select{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Phone Collection</h1>
    <form action="">
   <label for="brands">Brand:
   <select id="brands" class="brands input">
        <option value="All">All</option>
      </select>
   <span class="error"></span>
   </label>

   <button type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
    <section></section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

There is some moment where `phones` is undefined so you have to set an empty array as its default value when you call `array.prototype.filter`.

So try to change this:

```
phones.filter(phone => phone.brand == brand);
```

To:

```
(phones || []).filter(phone => phone.brand == brand);
```

Comment: or maybe initialize phones as an empty array ?

Comment: Now when I submit the form i get this array: undefined:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:59401/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is it because my form submits to a page that doesn't exist? But that would be weird because there is a preventdefault on it?

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you are instantiating the `phones` variable on the fist line, but you are never assigning a value to it, so it will always be equal to `undefined`.

Check where you are getting the data for phones and make sure you are assigning it to the `phones` variable.